# How to have a function tell whether to apply on "this" or other element ID

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have a function like this:

```
function toggle(me, style) {
  var myelm = me == '' ? this : document.getElementById(me);
 
  myelm.classList = style; 
}
```

I want the function to know when it has to apply the style to the triggering element or to some other element like in the following examples:

```html
 <div onclick="toggle(this);"></div> <!--this function should apply to this element only-->
 <div onclick="toggle('otherelement');"></div> <!--this should apply to other element of the DOM-->
```

but it only works when the ID is specified, and wont apply on `this` as intended. What is wrong?

Comment: Why don't you pass the `style` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you pass a DOM element, in the second a (non-empty) string. So the condition `me == ''` that you check is not true in either case. Secondly, `this` is irrelevant in the function, since you never call it with a `this` binding (a `this` binding is not the same thing as passing `this` as argument).

You'll want to check the data type of the argument, and when it is a string, retrieve the DOM element, and otherwise just use the argument that was given (`me`) -- not `this`:

Another thing: you need to call the `toggle` method on the `classList` property:

```
function toggle(me, style) {
  var myelm = typeof me != 'string' ? me : document.getElementById(me);
 
  myelm.classList.toggle(style);
}
```

NB: make sure to also pass the second argument (style)!

Snippet:

```js
function toggle(me, style) {
  var myelm = typeof me != 'string' ? me : document.getElementById(me);
 
  myelm.classList.toggle(style);
}
```

```css
.highlight { background: yellow }
```

```html
<div id="otherelement">This is other element</div>

<p></p>

<div onclick="toggle(this, 'highlight');">toggle this</div>
<div onclick="toggle('otherelement', 'highlight');">toggle other element</div>
```

Comment: why is it compared against a string called string?

Comment: Because JavaScript's `typeof` operator evaluates to one of the following: 'string', 'boolean', 'number', 'object', 'function', 'bigint', 'symbol', 'null'. When you call the function with `this` it will be 'object', and when you call it with 'otherelement' it will be 'string'.

Comment: got it but it still wont work on my end.

Comment: never mind, my mistake. thank you

Comment: Added a runnable snippet.

Comment: thanks, works great.